# Non related activities

Tags: android

Is there any way to suppress or kill all activities and non crucial applications and background processes not related to a current activity?

I have an app that runs in real time and there are occasional intermittent timing hiccups which I am attributing to this.

Comment: Depending on how the kernel was compiled, you can call [sched_setscheduler](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/sched_getscheduler.2.html) in a jni library and set a round-robin scheduling policy on your process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android will do this automatically as it needs the resources.  Plus, that's kind of a jerk move to other applications.

There is also other things that can cause "hiccups" such as a really large garbage collection.

Comment: thanks for this. The hiccups don't have any consistent pattern even though what is being processed does.

Comment: Garbage collector runs whenever the VM tells it to run (even when you explicitly call System.gc() though it's sooner).  Plus, there are other factors that *could* cause hiccups.  I guess what I'm trying to say is, yes you can kill other `Activities` (task killers do it).  I don't know how to do it, personally, but in the end it hinders user experience because he/she doesn't expect that to happen (Why did my alarm app suddenly stop?!?!).  It's better to handle the problem on your end.